Do attempts to balance an ability by altering its mechanics fall under the umbrella of homebrew or house-rules?
To clarify. I was thinking of modifying the 'World in Miniature' feat from spheres of power in order to make it more relevant at higher levels and ask whether it would break the balance but I was stuck on whether to use 'house-rule' or 'homebrew' tag as while altering an existing ability falls under the purview of 'house-rule' tag, questions regarding whether an ability is balanced or not fall under 'homebrew-review' tag. As such I wish to ask whether alterations on a specific existing ability fall under 'house-rule' or 'homebrew' tag?

Closely related, possible duplicate: What distinction is being drawn between house-rules and homebrew?

Does this answer your question? What distinction is being drawn between house-rules and homebrew?

The framework described in the Q&A OSage linked seems to answer your question here.

I think this question is valuable on its own merits. We're being asked to disambiguate the situation of modifying an existing feature into something kinda new. That looks both like house rules and like homebrew depending on how you squint at it. It's worth having a single question that disambiguates the intersection being observed here.

There is no hard-and-fast line. The canonical question on the subject claims one, but

As this question demonstrates, there’s still substantial gray area here, not a sharp line between black and white.

That line is arbitrary and does not necessarily reflect the terms’ usage, here or elsewhere. The terms’ distinction is, in reality, subjective and ad hoc—“I’ll know it when I see it.”


These two facts are why even the top answer to the canonical question argues that the tags are largely interchangeable and maybe should be synonyms. So use whichever one feels right to you in this circumstance. That’s all anyone’s ever done, and it’s been fine. Or use both, if it makes you feel better.
If someone has an issue with your tag choice, they can say so, in comments on the question, or in Meta. Then we’ll have a specific question to consider, which is vastly easier. This question simply does not have any solid way to be answered in general, for all hypothetical questions, or even for all hypothetical “modification to an existing rule” questions.
